# KeyPress Event not working in asp.net Content Page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Following is my code.can anyone please tell me how to handle keypress event in asp.net content page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#txtdesc').keypress(function (e) {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        if (txt.length > 5) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdesc" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: a classic case that you need to take the rendered id as: `<%=txtdesc.ClientID%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%=txtdesc.ClientID %>').on("keypress", function (e) {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        if (txt.length > 5) {
            alert('Hai');    
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Use ClienID with your text box control because it is server control.

Comment: Yaa i have tried updated code also.Even though it is not working @RGS

Comment: @user3378910, I updated my answer again. Please check. I have removed one open bracket '(' before function(e). Please check.

Comment: @user3378910, You are welcome. Mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net changes the HTML Response on page generating. (for web controls) like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$txtdesc" id="**ctxxx_txtdesc**" />
```

so, you should use generated id attribute value by asp.net or a class attribute. like this:

```
$('#ctl00$txtdesc').on("keypress", (function (e) {
   ...
});

<asp:TextBox ID="txtdesc" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="**txtdesc**" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

$('.txtdesc').on("keypress", (function (e) {
       ...
    });
```